# dockerfile - zipping directory recursively with relative path

Tags: linux, docker, zip, dockerfile

I'm trying to download,pack and install in my container a few python modules that i need to upload as a zip for aws lambda.

My docker file :

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r requirements.txt -t "/app/dependencies/"
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r requirements.txt
RUN zip -r -j /app/lambda.zip /app/dependencies/*
```

I have the following directories structure :

```
-app
    -dependencies
        -folder1
        -folder2
        -dep3 (file)
```

I'm trying to create a zip file in /app that contains the content of the dependencies dir but with a relative path and not full path :

unzip -l /app/dependencies.zip :

```
folder1 
folder2 
dep3
```

In order to include the directories and its content I must use the -r flag. According to the docs if I want to use relative paths I need to use the -j flag. However when I use both of them I'm getting an error :

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)
The command '/bin/sh -c zip -r -j /app/lambda.zip /app/dependencies/*' returned a non-zero code: 16
```

Any idea how to create a zip file (zip extension) with those constraints ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my DockerFile a littlebit and it solved everything.
You need to change your WORKDIR and not use full pathes in the zip command :

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.8
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r requirements.txt -t "/app/dependencies/"
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/dependencies
RUN zip -r  lambda.zip *
```